# Пересечение нескольких множеств

Tags: java, сравнение, множества

Программа получает на вход N целых чисел - штрафные баллы i-ого участника и К - мощность множества (количество элементов в нем)

Необходимо выбрать К - элементное множество из уникальных по величине штрафных баллов. Необходимо вывести множество с минимальной суммой в порядке возрастания штрафных баллов через пробел или -1, если такое множество получить нельзя.

```
Пример_1:
Ввод:
7 1 
2 3 4 5 6 7 1
Вывод:
1

Пример_2:
Ввод:
8 9
5 6 1 2 3 4 1 2
Вывод:
-1

Пример_3:
Ввод:
10 5
55 1561 51 5 1 1 15 15 1 18
Вывод:
1 5 15 18 51
```

Написал я вот такой код:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] n1 = new int[n];
        int k = in.nextInt();
        int y = 0;
        TreeSet<Integer> array = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            n1[i] = in.nextInt();
            array.add(n1[i]);
        }
        if (k < n) {
            for (int j : array) {
                if (y != k) {
                    System.out.print(j + " ");
                    y++;
                } else break;
            }
        } else System.out.println(-1);
    }
}
```

В итоге он тесты приведенные выше проходит, но валится на остальных произвольно вводимых данных.
Может что-то после заполнения сета не так идет...может еще что-то, но понять не могу.
Подскажите, кто знает как разобраться, буду признателен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
int k = in.nextInt();
in.skip("\\s+");
String nums = in.nextLine();
if(k > n) System.out.println(-1);
else Stream.of(nums.split("\\s+"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .limit(k)
        .forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));
```

Я думаю, ваша ошибка в том, что вы поставили условие `k < n` вместо `k <= n`. Из-за этого не проходят тесты, в которых `k` и `n` равны. Понятное дело, что в таком случае должны просто вывестись все числа в порядке возрастания.

Для уверенности, не могли бы вы показать тесты, которые ваша программа не прошла?

Comment: Совершенно верно! Ошибка была именно в знаке <=

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Именно тесты с равными k и n и не проходили.

Comment: @СанСаныч Я ни на что не намекаю, но я дал ответ 22 часа назад, а другой пользователь добавил приписку про <= 6 часов назад. Я насчёт галочки.

Comment: Ах это! Это называется "кривые руки" и уставшие после работы глаза) Посмотрел на Ваш ответ, а галочку поставил на следующий))) Сорри, все поправил!

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример решения (отличие от вашего в условии k <= size):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int k = in.nextInt();

        TreeSet<Integer> array = new TreeSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int t = in.nextInt();
            array.add(t);
        }

        int size = array.size();

        if (k <= size) {
            for (int v : array)
                if (k-- > 0)
                    System.out.print(v + " ");
                else break;
        } else
            System.out.println(-1);
     }
 }
```